# EditText does not display text instantly on some phone

Tags: android

In some phones, when I put EditText on the bottom of the screen, texts do not display instantly. Texts display only when soft-keyboard disappears(because of screen refresh). When I put editText on the top of soft-keyboard they are no problem.

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:maxLines="6"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="11dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue_text_style"
    android:id="@+id/titrePoste"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btShare"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:hint="@string/Objet"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/color1"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray" />
```

java code

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_pic_apercu);
titrePoste = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titrePoste);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happens sometimes maybe you should add hardware Accelerated in manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```